# e.SelectedItem.ToString() produces class name Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, selecteditem

I'm new to Xamarin.Forms and despite my searching, I have been unsuccessful in getting the strings associated with the selected items bindable properties in my ListView.  The goal is to take action based on the selected item. I've defined my UI in XAML as follows:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="EdgeNet.EdgeNetAddModule">
<StackLayout Padding="10">
    <Label Text="" FontSize="12" />
    <Label Text="Add Module" TextColor="#00A79D" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="36"/>
    <Label Text="" FontSize="12"/>
    <ListView x:Name="moduleTypesListView"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
        Header="Select A Module" 
        ItemSelected="OnSelection"
        RowHeight="80">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="#00A79D" Detail="{Binding Detail}" DetailColor="#A7A9AC"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <Image Source="Logo.png" />
```

I have bound the listview to an ObservableCollection in the code-behind as follows:

```
 moduleTypesListView.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Products>()
        {
            new Products {Name = "Outlet", Detail = "Standard 3-Prong Residential"},
            new Products {Name = "Switch", Detail = "Standard Wall Switch"},
            new Products {Name = "Thermostat", Detail = "edgeNet Smart Thermostat"}
        };
```

I would like to open a specific activity based on the item selected.  My event handler is as follows e.SelectedItem.ToString() returns "EdgeNet.Products" for any selected item:

```
        void OnSelection(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            return; //ItemSelected is called on deselection, which results in SelectedItem being set to null
        }

        Console.WriteLine(e.SelectedItem.ToString()); //This outputs the class name Products

        //Disable visual ugly orange highlighter for selected item
        ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;

        //ToDo: Figure out which item was selected and start setup routine
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your help.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple here, just not sure what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e.SelectedItem` is a `Product`, so you can cast it and then access it's properties

```
var product = (Product) e.SelectedItem;

if (product.Name == "blah") {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I knew I was missing something simple.